# What is the time-complexity of this function?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o

What is the Time complexity of this algorithm?

I understand that array.map have O(n) where n is the length of the array. I have also read that string.slice() also have a time complexity of O(n). However, since slice is dependent on the length of the word, is it right for me to say that the Time Complexity is 0(n + m), where m is the length of the words.

```
function sentenceCaps(str) {
  if (!str) {
    return new Error('empty string');
  }

  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  let results = arr.map(word => {return word[0].toUpperCase()+ word.slice(1)});
  return results.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the `str`

Comment: I doubt that in practice `string.slice()` is O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the time-complexity of this function?

O(*n*).

> is it right for me to say that the Time Complexity is 0(n + m), where m is the length of the words.

No, because *m* is roughly equal to *n*. Even if we assume that `String.slice()` is O(*n*) in the length of the result, the total number of letters sliced is a fraction of *n*, so it is already factored into the complexity. In practice, this is probably a constant-time operation.

(Analyzing the time complexity of any Javascript code is a little fuzzy, as the language makes no guarantees about the time complexity of any operations, and the runtime is capable of making some extremely powerful optimizations.)

Comment: "*`m` is roughly equal to `n`*" - I wouldn't say that. They might have quite different magnitudes, and I'd go for `n = l * m` where `n` is the length of the input string, `m` is the average length of a word and `l` is the number of words in the input. With that, we can determine the overall time complexity of `O(n + l * m)`, which of course is the same as `O(n)`.

Comment: @Bergi My assumption was that _m_ represented the total length of all words (i.e, the number of non-space characters, which is somewhere between _n/2_ and _n_), not the average length of each word.

Comment: Ah ok, then it makes sense.